# Javascript window.onload Not Waiting for DOM to Load

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am somewhat new to programming and have been working through the Head First HTML5 Programming book.  On page 65, they have an exercise that helps you insert a javascript function into the HTML head that will change the text located at bullet points in the body of the page.  When I open the HTML file in the browser, the page loads, but the content from the Javascript function isn't added to the bullet points.  I have determined it's because the script is running before the DOM is complete because when I change the book's code to `<body onload="addSongs()">`, the page loads correctly.

Here's the code from the book (that doesn't seem to work):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Playlist</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
function addSongs() {
var song1 = document.getElementById("song1");
var song2 = document.getElementById("song2");
var song3 = document.getElementById("song3");

song1.innerHTML = "Blue Suede Strings, by Elvis Pagely";
song2.innerHTML = "Great Objects on Fire, by Jerry JSON Lewis";
song3.innerHTML = "I Code the Line, by Johnny Javascript";

window.onload = addSongs;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> My Awesome Playlist! </h1>
<ul id="playlist">
<li id="song1"></li>
<li id="song2"></li>
<li id="song3"></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I have read through different posts and many people suggested using JQuery (which I'm hoping to learn in the next few months), but I'm just curious as to whether the `window.onload = function;` has been deprecated since this book was published or if I am making a mistake somewhere.  A lot of the exercises in this book use this principle and I can't move forward until I figure this out.  Any suggestions or different approaches are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the line:

```
window.onload = addSongs;
```

To *outside* the function.

> *"I have determined it's because the script is running before the DOM is complete"*

The script is running, but all it does is declare a function, it doesn't ever call it (because the aforementioned line is in the wrong place).

Comment: Thank you for your responses, they were all very helpful and make perfect sense.  Now my code works and I've been able to get the next few exercises done as well.  @Hazem

Answer (score 0):

it's just a typo.

you put `window.onload = addSong;` in the definition of the function addSong. so window.onload will never be set, as addSong will never be called.

```
function addSongs() {
    var song1 = document.getElementById("song1");
    var song2 = document.getElementById("song2");
    var song3 = document.getElementById("song3");

    song1.innerHTML = "Blue Suede Strings, by Elvis Pagely";
    song2.innerHTML = "Great Objects on Fire, by Jerry JSON Lewis";
    song3.innerHTML = "I Code the Line, by Johnny Javascript";

}

window.onload = addSongs; //move this line out of function definition.
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond... it was very helpful.  Take care!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `window.onload = addSongs;` after define the function, not before it.
like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Playlist</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
function addSongs() {
    var song1 = document.getElementById("song1");
    var song2 = document.getElementById("song2");
    var song3 = document.getElementById("song3");

    song1.innerHTML = "Blue Suede Strings, by Elvis Pagely";
    song2.innerHTML = "Great Objects on Fire, by Jerry JSON Lewis";
    song3.innerHTML = "I Code the Line, by Johnny Javascript";
}
window.onload = addSongs;

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> My Awesome Playlist! </h1>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li id="song1"></li>
    <li id="song2"></li>
    <li id="song3"></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```